# XML get value of element with : (colon) in name?

Tags: google-apps-script

Please,

When parsing RSS feed, there is name space with colon like: "**content:encoded**" and i cant get text value from it.

Found some explanation with iterating XML items ([link](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps-script/62rgQxHrAwk/u6SeLYQiFccJ)), but that I cant use, must use known name and then grab the value.

Is there any way to grab the value?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Look for something like the following namespace detail in the starting of the xml document, or parse it programatically :

```
<rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
>
```

Then you can use

```
var url ="http://blog.com/feed";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var xml = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), false);
var itemArray = xml.getElement().getElement("channel").getElements("item");


//Use the URI from namespace details below (Example for <content:encoded>)
var data = itemArray[0].getElement("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/","encoded").getText();
```